# What will happen to Indra's wife Shachi and Indra's mother Aditi when Bali takes over the post of Indra in 8th manvantara?

Tags: puranas, bhagavata-purana, indra, matsya-purana

In the Vamana Avatara, Lord Vishnu had given a boon to Asura king Bali that he would become Indra in the 8th manvantara. So what will happen to Aditi and Shachi? Will they leave the heaven with present Indra Shakra or they will continue to reside in heaven?

Comment: If Indra is just a post occupied by different jivas, why can't Indrani also be a post occupied by different jivas?

Comment: Their life span is of just 1 manvantara...

Comment: @YDS Should I delete my question as it seems duplicate?

Comment: Deletion not needed @Kiran